# Applying functions/methods within each sublist, not to the list of sublists as a whole in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've tried a few things to correctly make this function but nothing I try seems to be working. I think I have somewhat of an idea of what to do but how I am trying to do it isn't working out. So I already have a function called **string_avg(L)** that I think I can use for this function. **string_avg(L)** is defined by the following code:

```
      '''(list of str) -> list of list
    Given a list of strings where each string has the format:
    'name, grade, grade, grade, ...' return a new list of 
    lists where each inner list has the format :
[name (str), average grade (float)]
Requirement: This function should be 1 line long.
>>> string_avg(['Jo, 92, 80', 'Bill, 60, 70', 'Cal, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98'])
[['Jo', 86.0], ['Bill', 65.0], ['Cal', 98.0]]
'''
```

But now I need to write a code for the following:

```
def string_avg_update(L):
'''(list of str) -> NoneType
Given a list of strings where each string has the format:
'name, grade, grade, grade, ...' update  the given 
list of strs to be a list of floats where each item 
is the average of the corresponding numbers in the 
string. Note this function does NOT RETURN the list.
>>> L = ['Jo, 50, 92, 80', 'Bill, 60, 70', 'Cal, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98']
>>> string_avg_update(L)
>>> L 
[89.0, 65.0, 98.0]
'''
```

So to get string_avg_update(L), I though of perhaps using **string_avg(L)** which would give me [['Jo', 86.0], ['Bill', 65.0], ['Cal', 98.0]] , and then deleting the name from each sublist and joining the remaining int's from each list into one list. Is there a way to do this? I don't know how I would delete the first character in a list but know list.pop() deletes the last character in a list so if I used list.reverse() to put the numbers first within each sublist I could delete the name and then join the sublists together if possible. However, using list.reverse reverses the order of the sublists (ie. the Cal one comes first) instead of reversing the items within each sublist? Is there a way to make it so each list is reversed so I could use list.pop() (if I can figure out how to use it on each sublist).

Or is there a way to delete only strings from a list so I could join all sublists then delete the names. **Or maybe the best idea** would be to use del to delete the name from each sublist(i.e. by using del list[0]) but once again I don't know how to have del go through each sublist if I used it just as del list[0] it would delete the first sublist not the first character in each sublist.

I guess one key question here is how to apply functions/methods to every individual sublist and not to the sublists as a list.

Thanks!!

Comment: this seems to be the perfect place to use dictionnary no?

Comment: You should really think about a list comprehension here. Think about how you'd select the second element (the grade) from any *one* list: `L[1]`, right? So how could I then select that element from *every* sublist?

Comment: I guess that is my question.. does it work if I use "for sublist in L:" then write something under it about only selecting L[1] or something about deleting L[0]?

Comment: @Rir8 Yes, that could work. You know that `list.pop()` takes an *index* as its argument, right?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when I do it but I'll keep trying different things similar to that - thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries might be a better data structure for what you are trying to achieve.
However here is a solution that works with lists and the one line limits:

First to get the averages with the names:

```
def av_grade(lst):
    """(list of str)->list of list
    Given a list of strings where each string has the format:
    'name, grade, grade, grade, ...' return a new list of 
    lists where each inner list has the format :
    [name (str), average grade (float)]
    Requirement: This function should be 1 line long.

    >>> avg_grade(['Jo, 92, 80', 'Bill, 60, 70', 'Cal, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98'])
    [['Jo', 86.0], ['Bill', 65.0], ['Cal', 98.0]]
    """
    return [[x.split()[0], sum(map(float, x.split()[1:]))/(len(x.split()) - 1)] for x in ";".join(lst).replace(",", "").split(";")]
```

Now to get a flat list of only the averages:

```
def av_grade_update(lst):
    """(list of str)->[float, float, ...]
    Given a list of strings where each string has the format:
    'name, grade, grade, grade, ...' return a new with the format :
    [average grade (float), average grade (float)]
    Requirement: This function should be 1 line long.

    >>> avg_grade_update(['Jo, 92, 80', 'Bill, 60, 70', 'Cal, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98'])
    [86.0, 65.0, 98.0]
    """
    return [sum(map(float, x.split()[1:]))/(len(x.split()) - 1) for x in ";".join(lst).replace(",", "").split(";")]
```

Note both functions operate on the original list. This is to avoid mutating the original list because once mutated in the way you wanted originally, the original information is lost irrevocably (in the program at least).